# Excel formula for leaving a cell until data is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to enter a formula for leaving a cell blank until I enter data in another cell.

example for formula I need is in D12:  if c12 is TE then enter 6.79 or if C12 is TD then enter 7.99 otherwise leave blank.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(C12="TE",6.79,  IF(C12="TD",7.99,"")  )
```

There is an ISBLANK formula, but strictly speaking you don't need to use it for this scenario. What you are really trying to check is not when the cell is blank, but rather when the cell has one of two particular values. I used a nested IF formula as it's perfect for that.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I new there had to be an answer.

Comment: @CindyH Please mark this as the answer.